# Не возвращается 404 на странице удаленного товара wordpress

Tags: http-status-code-404, wordpress

Может кто-то встречался с такой проблемой.

На wordpress стоит wp-e-commerce, когда переходишь по ссылке удаленного товара, либо просто вводишь набор букв вместо товара (например, /catalogue/telefonyi-i-smartfonyi/sony/fdsafsafaf), то 404 ошибка не возвращается, а просто переходит на страницу /catalogue/telefonyi-i-smartfonyi/sony/,также и со всеми категориями.

Вроде настройки все проверила, в .htaccess ничего подобного нет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вдруг кому-то пригодится, вставила в самое начало page.php такой код:

```
<?php
if(wpsc_is_in_category()&&!wpsc_is_single_product()){

 if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['product_url_name'])) {
// echo $wp_query->query_vars['product_url_name'];
   header("HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found"); 
   include("/var/www/elite/data/www/nokia-elite.ru/content/themes/nokiaelite/404.php"); 
   die();
 }
 }
?>
```